# ValueError at / time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Tags: python, json, django, api, datetime

I'm working on a project in which when users mention a specific date range from and to, the corresponding data gets printed. The page takes input from users through input type date when the specific date is mentioned the value of date passes to `user_input_date_to` and `user_input_date_to`. But when I'm executing I'm getting the error  `ValueError at / time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`

My views file

```
def indexview(request):
    url=requests.get('https://data.covid19india.org/v4/min/timeseries.min.json')
    json_data=url.json()

    user_input_state=''
    user_input_date_from=''
    user_input_date_to=''
    user_data_type=''
    user_required_type=''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_input_state=request.POST.get('state')
        x=request.POST['date_from']
        user_input_date_to=request.POST['date_to']
        user_data_type=request.POST.get('data_period')
        user_required_type=request.POST.get('required_type')
        #To store dates list
    start_date =user_input_date_from
    end_date = user_input_date_to
    start_date_object = dt.datetime.strptime(start_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
    end_date_object = dt.datetime.strptime(end_date,"%Y-%m-%d").date()
    days = end_date_object - start_date_object
    dates=[]
    otp=[]
    for i in range(days.days+1):
        dates.append(str(start_date_object+dt.timedelta(days=i)))
    
    for i in dates:
        try:
            otp.append(json_data[user_input_state]['dates'][i][user_data_type][user_required_type])
        except KeyError:
            otp.append(0)
    
    dict_pass={
        'dates':dates,
        'otp':otp
        }
    return render(request,'index.html',dict_pass)
```

HTML date form

```
 <input type="date" name="date_from"><br>  
 <input type="date" name="date_to">
```

Comment: you seem to pass an empty string to `datetime.strptime`. did you make sure the date/time is defined in the JSON`?

Comment: The functions `user_input_date_from` or `user_input_date_to` are assigned to `start_date` and `end_date` respectively but not called in the given code (i.e, missing `()` at the end). Please change this and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: @MrFuppes @unityJarvis when I pass ``` user_input_date_from or user_input_date_to='2021-11-10'  (some random date) ``` and if I commented ``` user_input_date_to=request.POST['date_to']
        user_data_type=request.POST.get('data_period') ``` then the code is working, not able to figure out what's wrong

Comment: You could provide the whole error trace, particularly the line which bings the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are trying to create `datetime` object of format `'%Y-%m-%d'` from the invalid user input (in your case it's empty string).

You should validate user input first, then do the business logic.

You could do it manually, or try to use existing libraries for the validation
(e.g. [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) ...)

Comment: Not able to figure out how to validate when I printed user_input_from value I got the format YYYY-MM-DD (ex: 2021-101-11) which is my desired form, if I commented the  user_input_date_to=request.POST['date_to'] and just declared initially user_input_date_from or user_input_date_to='2021-11-11 I'm getting my output.

Comment: if  `request.method` not equal `'POST':` than you pass to `strptime` function initial value that is stored  in the `user_input_date_from` which is empty string